# ToDate function provides unexpected output

Tags: apache-pig, to-date

I used the `ToDate(userinput, format)` function to covert my chararray field. I used the `ToDate(userinput, 'MM/dd/yyyy')` to covert the field from chararray to `date` but looks like i am not seeing the output as i had expected.

Here is the code:

```
l_dat = load 'textfile' using PigStorage('|') as  (first:chararray,last:chararray,dob:chararray);

c_dat = foreach l_dat generate ToDate(dob,'MM/dd/yyyy') as mydate;
describe c_dat;
dump c_dat;
```

data looks like this:

```
(firstname1,lastname1,02/02/1967)
(John,deloy,05/26/1967)
(frank,fun,05/18/1967)
```

Output looks like this:

```
c_dat: {mydate: datetime}
(1967-05-26T00:00:00.000-04:00)
(1967-05-18T00:00:00.000-04:00)
(1967-02-02T00:00:00.000-05:00)
```

The output i was expecting was dateObjects with data as shown below:

```
(05/26/1967)
(05/18/1967)
(02/02/1967)
```

Please advise if i am doing anything wrong?

Comment: maybe add another for loop like they did on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933900/human-readable-string-date-converted-to-date-using-pig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-date, the return type of ToDate function is DateTime object. You can observe that in the schema description shared in output

```
c_dat: {mydate: datetime}
```

If you are having the date in the required format, you need not do any conversion.

```
c_dat = foreach l_dat generate dob as mydate;
```

If you are interested in converting the chararray date to any other format then you have to use ToString() function after getting the DateTime object.

```
  Step 1: Convert date chararray to Date Time Ojbect using ToDate(datesstring, inutformat)
  Step 2 : Use ToString(DateTime object, required format) to get the string date in the required format.
```

This can be achieved in a single step as below.

```
ToString(ToDate(date,inputformat),requiredformat);
```

Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-string for details.